# Copying files of Windows partition using rsync gives readlink_stat(...) Input/output error (5)

Tags: windows, ntfs, rsync, copy

I want to copy all files of a Windows 10 system partition (NTFS) to another partition (NTFS).

I am using `rsync` under Ubuntu like this:

```
sudo rsync -axHAWXS --numeric-ids /media/windows /mnt/windows-backup
```

The problem is that several thousand files cannot be read.

> rsync: readlink_stat("/media/windows/Program Files (x86)/Reference
> Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0/de/PresentationFramework.resources.dll")  failed: Input/output error (5)
> rsync: readlink_stat("/media/windows/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0/de/ReachFramework.resources.dll")  failed: Input/output error (5)
> ...

Upon listing the contents of a directory with those files using

```
sudo ls -l "/media/windows/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0/de/"
```

I get the following output:

> ls: cannot access '/media/windows/Program Files (x86)/Reference
> Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0/de/PresentationFramework.resources.dll': Input/output error
> ls: cannot access '/media/windows/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0/de/ReachFramework.resources.dll': Input/output error
> ...
> -????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? PresentationFramework.resources.dll
> -????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? ReachFramework.resources.dll
> ...

I listing a few of those files under Windows 10 without any problems fine (file explorer and shell).

I checked the filesystem, it is undamaged. The Windows system is running without any problems.

What is the problem? How can I copy those files?

Comment: What OS are you running rsync from?

Comment: @DavidPostill Good point! It's Ubuntu (18.04 installed/20.04 as live CD, tried both) Edited my answer

Comment: [rsync - How to interpret and fix a Input/output error in Linux? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/676649/how-to-interpret-and-fix-a-input-output-error-in-linux)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, but I already ruled that out. An antivirus problem cannot be the problem because Windows is not running during copying. Additionally listing those files under Windows itself works without problems (put that into my answer), so I can't be a defect file system (ran fsck under Ubuntu as well).